# How do I create a CSV file with sequence pig script?

Tags: apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a CSV file with a column to which I would add a sequence of numbers and then link the fields with a join.

```
Column_A
-----------
claudio
carlo
pierluigi
giovanni
```

Result:

```
Column_A    |Column_B
---------------------
claudio     | 1
carlo       | 2
pierluigi   | 3
giovanni    | 4
```

Alternatively is there a method to merge two columns of two files that have fields which are to join in?

FILE 1:

```
Column_A
-------------
claudio
carlo
pierluigi
giovanni
```

FILE 2:

```
Column_B
-------------
napoli
roma
milano
genova
```

Result:

```
Column_A   | Column_B
---------------------
claudio    | napoli
carlo      | roma
pierluigi  | milano
giovanni   | genova
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways, you can use Apache Pig to do what you want to do.

Since 0.11 version you can use [RANK](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/basic.html#rank) operator.

```
-- First load your csv file
A1 = LOAD '/path/to/file/file1.csv USING PigStorage(',') AS(name:CHARARRAY);
-- Then RANK
B1 = RANK A1;
-- Look at the results 
DUMP B;
-- First load your csv file
A2 = LOAD '/path/to/file/file2.csv USING PigStorage(',') AS(city:CHARARRAY);
B2 = RANK A2;
--- Then join by id (row number)
C = JOIN B1 BY $0, B2 BY $0;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's very kind of you